# IAS math problem 2017-paper 1 4a

Tags: analytic-geometry, 3d

Reduce the following equation into standard form and hence determine the nature of coincoid $x^2+y^2+z^2-zx-xy-yz-3x-6y-9z+21=0$

I have reduced the equation into $(x-3/2)^2 +(y-3)^2 + (z-9/2)^2 -zx -xy-yz = 21/2$ from here on I can sense to reduce it to any of the standard 3D form that I am aware of(like ellipse, ellipsoid, hyperboloid, etc.,). Please help me out in the same.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This is not a site for homework. Please show us that you made an effort if you want an answer.

Comment: Hi @Pippo, your response is appreciated. I am new to this website and I don't know the norm of showing my effort while posting a query my apologies for that. Secondly this is not a homework problem rather is a problem asked in prestigious Indian Administrative service exam(top most bureaucratic post in INDIA)
I made a ton of effort before posting this here,please let me know how to post my work here? can I post my rough work here or should I just post in the final step where i am stuck?

Comment: I'd say rough work is preferable. We like having lots of detail. Refer to [this thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) on how to ask a good question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just to find the nature of the surface does not require an orthonormal coordinate change. Take
$$ u = x+y+z, \; \; \; v = -x + y, \; \; \; w = -x - y + 2z \; \; .  $$
$$ 6u = \frac{3}{4} (v-1)^2 + \frac{1}{4} (w-3)^2 + 18 $$
which is a paraboloid. The $6u$ stuff does not show this, but it is a paraboloid of revolution. One could correct $u,v,w,$ in particular dividing by $\sqrt 3, \sqrt 2, \sqrt 6,$ to get a strictly rotated version. The axis of symmetry (actually of revolution, as I said) is parallel to $(1,1,1)$ in the original $(x,y,z)$ coordinates, and the vertex is at $(0,1,2).$

Having done that much, we get an orthonormal change taking $u = p \sqrt 3,$ $v = q \sqrt 2,$ $w = r \sqrt 6.$ 
$$ 6 p \sqrt 3 = \frac{3}{4} (q \sqrt 2-1)^2 + \frac{1}{4} (r \sqrt 6-3)^2 + 18, $$
$$ 6 p \sqrt 3 = \frac{3}{2} (q -\frac{1}{\sqrt 2})^2 + \frac{3}{2} (r  - \frac{3}{\sqrt 6})^2 + 18, $$
$$ 4 p \sqrt 3 =(q -\frac{1}{\sqrt 2})^2 +  (r  - \frac{3}{\sqrt 6})^2 + 12 \; \; , $$
$$  p  = \frac{1}{4 \sqrt 3} \left(\left(q -\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\right)^2 +  \left(r  - \frac{3}{\sqrt 6}\right)^2 + 12 \right) \; \; . $$

Comment: Thanks a lot... :)

Answer (score 0):

I got that our equation it's
$$(x-y+7)^2+(y-z+1)^2+(z-x-8)^2=36(x+2).$$
I think from here we can  get $x=-2$, but I don't see this.